# Swap out repositories with a flag

Tags: domain-driven-design, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have an IRepository< T > interface with many T's and several implementations (on-demand DB, web service, etc.). I use AutoFac to register IRepository's for many T's depending on the kind of repository I want for each T.

I also have a .NET-caching-based implementation that looks for T's in cache and then calls a 'real' IRepository.Find to resolve a cache miss. It is constructed something like this:

```
new CachingRepository(realRepository, cacheImplementation);
```

I would like to use a configuration flag to decide if AutoFac serves up caching-based IRepository's or the 'real things.' It seems like 'realRepository' comes from asking AutoFac to resolve IRepository < T > but then what do clients get when they ask to resolve the same interface? I want them to get the CachingRepository if the flag is set.

I can't get my head around how to implement this flag-based resolution. Any ideas?

Comment: You might also consider implementing caching as an aspect, which gets attached to the `realRepository` by AutoFac only if caching is enabled.  Might cut down on the amount of cache related code you have to maintain.

Comment: In a similar vein, Autofac also supports method interception via DynamicProxy2 http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DynamicProxy2

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028747/caching-code-location-in-a-domain-driven-design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simplest Option:  Conditional Registration Delegate**

There are a number of ways to do this.  Using your cache setting in a registration delegate is probably the simplest (and illustrates the power of delegate registrations):

```csh
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

bool cache = GetCacheConfigSetting(); //Up to you where this setting is.    

builder.Register(c => cache ? (IRepository<string>)new CachingRepository<string>(new RealRepos<string>(), new CacheImpl()) : new RealRepos<string>());
```

The code above will only read the cache config once.  You could also include the `GetCacheConfigSetting()` in the registration delegate.  This would result in the setting being checked on every `Resolve` (assuming `InstancePerDependency`).

**Other Options: Autofac Decorators and Modules**

There are some more advanced features of Autofac that you may also find useful.  The cache class in your question is an example of the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).  [Autofac has explicit support for decorators](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/decorator-support-in-autofac-2-4/).  It also has a nice model for structuring your registrations and managing configuration information, called [Modules](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules).

Comment: This is brilliant. I've been using the delegate-registration for other reasons and it's the perfect solution to this.