# Creating an Autofac Lifetimescope that will expire with time

Tags: autofac

I have a bank/collection which caches instances of objects in memory so that each request doesn't need to go back to the datastore. I'd like Autofac to provide an instance of this bank, but then expire it after x seconds, so that a new instance is created on the next request. I'm having trouble getting my head around setting up a LifetimeScope to achieve this. I've read through [this](http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/) a couple of times. The Bank object is not really subject to a unit of work. It will ideally reside 'above' all units of work, caching objects within and across them.

I'm currently using the approach below, however it isn't working as I'd hoped.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
....
builder.Register(c =>
            {
                return new ORMapBank(c.Resolve<IORMapRoot>());
            }).InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(ExpireTimeTag.Tag());


        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        var TimedCache= RootScope.BeginLifetimeScope(ExpireTimeTag.Tag());
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(TimedCache));
```

....

```
public static class ExpireTimeTag
{
    static DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    static Object tag = new Object();

    public static object Tag()
    {
        if (d.AddSeconds(10) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            CreateTag();
        return tag;
    }

    private static void CreateTag()
    {
        tag = new Object();
    }
}
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is common to use a caching decorator to achieve this kind of behaviour.  Assuming your `IORMapRoot` is responsible for getting the data in question (but it would work the same if `ORMapBank`) you do the following:

- Create a new type, `CachingORMapRoot` that implements `IORMapRoot`
- Add a constructor that takes the expiry `TimeSpan` and an instance of the original `IORMapRoot` implementation.
- Implement the members to call the underlying instance and then cache the results accordingly for subsequent calls (implementation will vary on your cache technology).
- Register this type in the container as `IORMapRoot`

This is a very clean way to implement such caching.  It also makes it easy to [switch between cached and non-cached implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226194/swap-out-repositories-with-a-flag).

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Worked a treat. Looks like I was way off track.

I'm now in a position where I can say goodbye to session state! This is momentous. I feel like I should light a candle or something to mark the moment :-)

Comment: Hooray!  Glad to be of help.  Next time someone says "DI has no use and is too complicated" you can tell them the story of this day, and the candle :) *Of course you don't need DI to do this, but it makes it easy to add cross-cutting concerns like caching, when you need it.*

Comment: It's funny you know. We had a web company in here the other day consulting on best practise. To be fair, they were very good. I was surprised though when the lead tech dismissed DI as not needed and too complicated. I'm nearly finished implementing Autofac in my current project and I have to say that I've been really surprised how little code it's required. All up, I think that I've only needed 10-15 lines. Very impressive stuff :-)